# Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.1.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources(Android studio version Giraffe)

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

After updating my Android studio to Giraffe version when I create a new project I faced an error says

> Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.1.0', apply: false]
> was not found in any of the following sources:

After many tries and searches I couldn't fix.

**Build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.webjow.myapplication"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.webjow.myapplication"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

Comment: Did u fixed? I change the distributionUrl still the same error

Comment: Hi Murtaza, Have you found solutions for this issues?

Comment: @Htut
Change the gradle-8.1-bin.zip to version 8.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by changing distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.1-bin.zip

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by removing the proxy settings from the **gradle.properties** file in Android Studio. To do this, open the **gradle.properties** file and remove the following lines:

```
proxyHost=
proxyPort=
```

Save the file and try running your project again. The error should be gone.

Here is a more detailed explanation of the steps involved:

1. Open the gradle.properties file in Android Studio.
2. Find the lines that start with proxyHost and proxyPort.
3. Remove these lines.
4. Save the file.
5. Try running your project again.

Comment: I can't file those line in my  gradle.properties

Comment: Also you might set your proxy off in Settings

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you enabled Gradle offline mode, try disable it.